# Bash ls with double substitution

Tags: bash, ls, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

I am writing a bash script that reads a directory from the command line arguments and performs an `ls` on it.

If I specify a simple directory, then all is OK.

But I want do something like `/home/{x,y}`, so the invocation of the script is `my-script -d '/home/{x,y}'`  The value of `'/home/{x,y}'` is stored in a variable named `source`.

- I tried `ls "${source}"`, but it returns

  ```
  ls: cannot access /home/{x,y}: No such file or directory
  ```
- I tried `ls ${!source}`, but it returns the files in the current directory.
- I tried `ls \$$source`, but again, it fails with the first error.

How can I expand the parameter `'/home/{x,y}'` inside my script so that it runs `ls /home/x /home/y`?

Comment: Could you be more detailed on the script? How are you reading in arguments, how are you executing the `ls`? And do you know about `eval`?

Comment: Running `my-script -d /home/{x,y}` would be expanded to `my-script -d /home/x /home/y` by the shell _before_ your script is invoked.  Are you quoting that parameter?

Comment: @AndyDalton, true though note that it's only if the calling shell supports csh-style brace expansions. Not all shells support it and not all shells that support it have it enabled by default. Until very recently POSIX prohibited it being supported by `sh` implementations.

Comment: If you want your script to consider `/home/{x,y}` as if it was `/home/x` and `/home/y`, how would the caller specify a directory called literally `/home/{x,y}`?

Comment: pls check my answer below

Comment: @Fiximan What do you mean more detailed about the script. It is basically parse the command line arguments with getopt and then literally doing the ls "${source}" command. I can include the full script if you would like. I have read about eval, but how can it be useful in my situation, should I test ls `eval ${source}` maybe?

Comment: @AndyDalton I call my script my-script -d '/home/{x,y}', so that it will not perform any substitution at its invocation. I would like to perform this invocation at the commanf ls

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas One would call my-script -d /home/\{x,y\} I suppose, but I will not have such scripts in my server. I want to retrieve the latest backup from the server, and the backups are under /home/backup/monthly and /home/backup/weekly. So, I thought that instead of allowing multiple cmd arguments -d, that I could do it in one, bur I am stuck at the ls. It either takes the argument literally and outputs there is no such directory or it is completely disregarded and outputs the current directory contents.

Comment: @AlexiosTsiaparas `ls` won't do that substitution -- that's up to the shell.  Try something like `ls $(sh -c "echo $@")`

Comment: @AndyDalton Thanks a lot man, this solved my problem!!! Can you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do that is to pass the directories as the main command line arguments, without requiring option flags. I.e. the user would run `my-script -a -b foo /home/me/dir1 /some/other/path`. After running `getopts` to parse the options, you'd be left with the directories in the positional parameters and could just run `ls "$@"`. Here, the user can use whatever expansions their shell allows them to fill those last arguments, be it `/some/path/{foo,bar}`, or `/some/path/*`.

Alternatively, have the user pass multiple `-d` options, so they'd run `my-script -a -b foo -d /home/me/dir1 -d /some/other/path`. Here, it's harder to use expansions, since they'd need to add the `-d` in front of each argument with whatever their shell allows for. Perhaps with something like `a=(/path/{this,that}); my-script -a -b foo "${a[@]/#/-d}"`.

In any case, replicating the shell's expansions within a script is not a common thing to do, and may well catch your users off guard, so I'd advise against it.
If you do that, you'd also need to decide on *which* expansions to support. Not all shells support all expansions, and not all users know all expansions supported by each shell.

Answer (score 0):

example.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILE_PATTERN="$1"
MATCHING_FILES=$(eval "echo $FILE_PATTERN")
echo "Files: $MATCHING_FILES"
ls -l $MATCHING_FILES
```

This will use the first argument to example.sh as a shell glob pattern. It will probably break on filenames containing spaces or special characters. How the variables should be quoted to avoid that, while still applying the pattern is for you to find out.

Usage:

```
$ ./example.sh 'file-{x,y}.txt'
Files: file-x.txt file-y.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  0 30 Sep 16:47 file-x.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user  group  0 30 Sep 16:47 file-y.txt
```

If at all possible, it would be better to *not* do this and instead accept multiple filenames as arguments. It would certainly make variable quoting clearer and easier, and you could avoid having to deal with the question asked by Stéphane about filenames that look like glob patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
#! /bin/bash -
sources=()
while getopts d:... o; do
  case $o in
    (d) sources+=("$OPTARG");;
    (...) ;;
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"

ls -- "${sources[@]}"
```

That is, have your script take a list of directories, where the caller uses one `-d` per directory.

Then the user can do:

```
my-script -d/home/{x,y}
```

if their shell supports brace expansion, or whatever their shell offers to facilitate building up that list.

In `rc`/`fish`/`zsh -o rcexpandparam`, that can be:

```
my-script -d$array
```

for instance (also `-d$^array` without `rcexpandparam` in `zsh`)

In `zsh`:

```
my-script /home/*(P[-d])
```

etc.

For your script to perform brace expansion on an argument and not the other forms of expansion, you could quote all sequences of characters other than `{`, `}` and `,` (and `.0-9` if you want to allow `{1..10}` style ones), and run it through `eval`.

It would be easier with `zsh` or `ksh93` as `bash`'s `${var//pattern/replacement}` is very limited:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
source=${1?}

set -o extendedglob
eval "sources=( ${source//(#m)[^"{}".,0-9]##/'$MATCH'} )"

printf ' - "%s"\n' "$sources[@]"
```

Example:

```
$ myscript 'x\{1..3}$$`{a b,c}'
 - "x\1$$`a b"
 - "x\1$$`c"
 - "x\2$$`a b"
 - "x\2$$`c"
 - "x\3$$`a b"
 - "x\3$$`c"
```

But then, the user wouldn't be able to pass a literal `foo{a,b}` argument anymore.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because it is evaluated as multiple arguments rather than just one. Try this:

```
ls "$@"
```

`$@` expands to all parameters into space separated strings.

Comment: I have more arguments, so this would not help in my situation unfortunately. If it suits you, I can post the code

Comment: have you tried this?